# how to go back 2 page before in flutter

Tags: flutter

Right now I am trying to delete data and when I am done delete it. It should be going to the homepage. The issue here is when I am using the navigator to the homepage. The user_id returns null instead of it should be showing the real user_id. How can I manage the flow of content?

Code that I use to go back 2 pages before.

```
 new RaisedButton(
      child: new Text("OK DELETE!",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),),
      color: Colors.red,
      onPressed: (){
        deleteData();
        Navigator.of(context).push(
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (BuildContext context)=> OwnerPage())
        );
      },
    ),
```

The image on before deleting occur:

[image]

The image on after deleting occur:

[image]

For additional information. From the login page to the home page, I am using this type of code:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using routes to navigate between pages you can do this

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context,'/OwnerPage');
```

this will directly navigate to the OwnerPage

Hope this is helpful!

Answer (score 2):

There are different approaches to navigate between pages. The bad one is, you can `Navigator.pop()` two times. The good one is, you need to add parameters:

```
  Navigator.of(context).push(
      MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (BuildContext context)=> OwnerPage(username: username, user_id: user_id)) // Add parameters
    );
```

Comment: thank you.. it works.. I love your bad idea, but the good one is working.. (>.<)